# Need to find possible combinations for two values in multiple columns

Tags: google-sheets, permutation, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, google-sheets-query

I'm trying to find patterns in products in a dataset of Transaction IDs.

The initial dataset lists transactions by ID in each row and every product in each transaction as a new column.

I want to find every combination of two products in 1 (each) transaction. and return them with a count of appearances of this (same) permutation in the dataset. However, it doesn't matter in which order products are. So Product B X Product A should be counted as Product A X Product

[image: sheet example]

In the image, you can see how the table looks (roughly) and what output I would need.

Does anyone have an idea on how to do this with Google Sheets?

Comment: What about the third transaction, where you have three products (B, A, D)?

Answer (score 0):

you can do this:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(QUERY(IF(
 {B2:B; B2:B; B2:B; C2:C; C2:C; D2:D}<
 {C2:C; D2:D; E2:E; D2:D; E2:E; E2:E}, 
 {B2:B; B2:B; B2:B; C2:C; C2:C; D2:D}&" "&
 {C2:C; D2:D; E2:E; D2:D; E2:E; E2:E}, 
 {C2:C; D2:D; E2:E; D2:D; E2:E; E2:E}&" "&
 {B2:B; B2:B; B2:B; C2:C; C2:C; D2:D}), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1) 
  where Col1 is not null 
    and not Col1 matches '^\s.+|^\s' 
  group by Col1 
  label Count(Col1)''", 0))
```

[image: 0]